# XAMPP, friendly URLs and htaccess - Worked on the actual site, can't get it to work locally

Tags: php, .htaccess, xampp

I used to develop my PHP web-project online/straight on my webhost through CodeAnywhere. Bad practice in the long run, I know, hence deciding to finally figure out how to work locally first.

So I downloaded all my files with FileZilla (including the htaccess file), installed XAMPP and managed to open it on localhost. So far, so good. But only the index page works. Any links to the other pages just show the index page.

In short, because I'm horribly cursed at explaining things:
Typing 'localhost:8000/bestillinger.php' works. But 'localhost:8000/bestillinger' does not.

Again, the above works perfectly on the online site.

I tried to write some garbage in the .htaccess file, and didn't get any errors, so I suppose it never loads. I also tried to rename .htaccess to .htaccess. because I saw someone mention it could be a Windows thing.

I've already tried the following by opening the Apache Config httpd.conf file in XAMPP:

- Look for 'AccessFileName' (doesn't exist in it?)
- Look for 'LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so' to remove the #, however, it was already removed by default.

I'm sorry if my question is poorly phrased or just dumb. I'm just self-taught and doing this stuff on hobby level getting demotivated by how complicated it seems to develop a PHP site locally, when it was so easy to do it on an online IDE.

Comment: First of all, go check what [`AllowOverride`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#allowoverride) and [`AccessFileName`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#accessfilename) are set to in your local Apache configuration.

Comment: In httpd.conf, right? Because 'AccessFileName' doesn't exist in it. I found 'AllowOverride none' but changing it to 'AllowOverride All' didn't do anything.

Comment: Apache uses different config files that are included into the main configuration, so check all of them. (Most likely the place to look should be `extras/httpd-default.conf`.)

Comment: Thank you. I found httpd-default.conf, and could find AccessFileName however it's already set to 'AccessFileName .htaccess'.

Comment: Did you restart the webserver after you made changes regarding `AllowOverride`?

Comment: I did, yes. I just tested again to make sure today, after computer's been off, and it's the same.

Comment: If “garbage” written in the .htaccess doesn’t result in any errors, then that is a pretty sure sign, that it currently does not get interpreted at all. Maybe `AllowOverride` from the httpd.conf got overwritten again in the virtual host configuration, a `Location` or `Directory` directive, or something like that.

Comment: Yeah, I get that .htaccess never gets loaded. Unfortunately I have never used this kind of thing before, and don't really know my way around any of it. I think I'll have to give up and find another solution, sadly. But thank you for your time and help at very least.